# Know the real bounds of an image in UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I am using an UIImageView to load an image with aspectfit. Hence the image does use the whole UIImageView surface. How to know what is the bounds of the image inside the UIImageView?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
CGFloat aspectRatioX = imageView.bounds.size.width/imageView.image.size.width;
CGFloat aspectRatioY = imageView.bounds.size.height/imageView.image.size.height;
if ( aspectRatioX < aspectRatioY )
    imageRect = CGRectMake(0, (imageView.bounds.size.height - aspectRatioX*imageView.image.size.height)*0.5f, imageView.bounds.size.width, aspectRatioX*imageView.image.size.height);
else
    imageRect = CGRectMake((imageView.bounds.size.width - aspectRatioY*imageView.image.size.width)*0.5f, 0, aspectRatioY*imageView.image.size.width, imageView.bounds.size.height);
```